# How to assign property value from DefaultValue attribute

Tags: c#

I have a class with a large count of properties (about 30), for example

```
 [DisplayName("Steps to stacker"), DefaultValue(20)]
 [Description("Value in obturator steps")]
 public int StepsToStacker { get; set; }

 [DisplayName("Enter time"), DefaultValue(120)]
 [Description("Value in milliseconds")]
 public int EnterTime { get; set; }
```

Is there a simple way to implement `LoadDefaultValues()` which load values from `DefaultValue` atrribute?

Comment: `DefaultValue` is deigned for `Designer` code, for `Components`. You've to use reflection or set it in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the intended use of the attribute is not to actually set the values of the properties, you can use reflection to always set them anyway.

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        {
            DefaultValueAttribute myAttribute = (DefaultValueAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];

            if (myAttribute != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, myAttribute.Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my qustion id duplicate. This code works fine

```
public void LoadDefaultValues()
{
   foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
       foreach (Attribute attr in p.GetCustomAttributes(true))
       {
           if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute)
           {
                DefaultValueAttribute dv = (DefaultValueAttribute)attr;
                p.SetValue(this, dv.Value, null);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the my answer ???